# GIT sems to be corrupting XLS Files

Tags: git

I have an XLS file that I've commited to a git repository, and pushed the git repository to [Stash](https://de.atlassian.com/software/stash).

I've created and commited the file on OSX. When I download it from Stash using OSX, the file is still intact. However, when I clone the repository on linux RHEL6, I get a different checksum?

Can I use `.gitattributes` to ensure that the file has the same checksum on all platforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be due to git thinking it is a text file, and converting CRLFs to LFs. Try putting the following in your .gitattributes file and see if it fixes the issue: `* -text`.